# How to find out the default values of a particular function's argument in another function in Python?

Tags: python, introspection, default-parameters

Let's suppose we have a function like this:

```
def myFunction(arg1='a default value'):
  pass
```

We can use introspection to find out the names of the arguments that `myFunction()` takes using `myFunction.func_code.co_varnames`, but how to find out the default value of `arg1` (which is `'a default value'` in the above example)?

Comment: Can I make this a Wiki instead? I'm unable to find out how to do it. I found out the answer shortly after asking the question, so since I answered my own question, it's better that I make it a wiki.

Comment: @Josh: Thanks. Got a much better answer from Duncan, and marked that one as the accepted answer instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As an alternative to rooting around in the attributes of the function you can use the inspect module for a slightly friendlier interface:

For Python 3.x interpreters:

```
import inspect
spec = inspect.getfullargspec(myFunction)
```

Then spec is a `FullArgSpec` object with attributes such as `args` and `defaults`:

```
FullArgSpec(args=['arg1'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=('a default value',), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```

Some of these attributes are not available on Python 2 so if you have to use an old version `inspect.getargspec(myFunction)` will give you a similar value without the Python 3 features (`getargspec` also works on Python 3 but has been deprecated since Python 3.0 so don't use it):

```
import inspect
spec = inspect.getargspec(myFunction)
```

Then spec is an `ArgSpec` object with attributes such as `args` and `defaults`:

```
ArgSpec(args=['arg1'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=('a default value',))
```

Comment: That's much better because you also get the variable names as well as their default values (if present)!

Comment: Note that this has deprecated since Python 3.0 in favour of `inspect.getfullargspec`

Answer (score 10):

If you define a function `f` like this:

```
>>> def f(a=1, b=True, c="foo"):
...     pass
...
```

in Python 2, you can use:

```
>>> f.func_defaults
(1, True, 'foo')
>>> help(f)
Help on function f in module __main__:
f(a=1, b=True, c='foo')
```

whereas in Python 3, it's:

```
>>> f.__defaults__
(1, True, 'foo')
>>> help(f)
Help on function f in module __main__:
f(a=1, b=True, c='foo')
```

Comment: Check out Duncan's answer, it's much better than this one.

Answer (score 1):

The `inspect.signature` also provides a nice way to iterate parameters of a function https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature

```py
import inspect

def f(*cake, one, two=None, three=3): pass

s = inspect.signature(f)
# <Signature (*cake, one, two=None, three=3)>
s.parameters['three'].default
3
s.parameters['cake'].kind
# <_ParameterKind.VAR_POSITIONAL: 2>
s.parameters['cake'].name
'cake'
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Of course, there's `myFunction.func_defaults`.