# Python: Passing the default values of function' arguments to *args or **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, default-value, metaclass

Consider example:

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@decorator
def foo(x, y, z=0):
    pass

foo(5, 5)
```

Output:

```
(5, 5) {}
```

Why not `(5, 5) {'z': 0}`? How to pass all default values of the function `foo` to `*args` or `**kwargs` using only decorator (for functions) or metaclass (for class methods, e.g. `__init__`)?

Comment: Also be aware that `wrapper` receives `(5, 5, 42)` if you use `foo(5, 5, 42)`, but it will receive `(5, 5), {'z': 42}` if you use `foo(5, 5, z=42)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrapper is just a normal function. It does not have "access" to the internals of the wrapped function.

You would have to use introspection to get them. See a related question:

[How to find out the default values of a particular function's argument in another function in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859993/how-to-find-out-the-default-values-of-a-particular-functions-argument-in-anothe)